# Socket error: connection refused - what am I doing wrong?

Tags: c, linux, sockets

I've just started learning the basics of sockets (Linux). I tried my hand at a small example, but it doesn't work and I have no idea what's wrong.

I get a "Connection Refused" error message.

---

Here's my code:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netinet/ip.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main() {
    int c;
    c = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (c < 0) {
        printf("Error in creating socket! %s\n", strerror(errno));
        return 1;
    }

    struct sockaddr_in server;
    memset(&server, 0, sizeof(server));
    server.sin_port = htons(1234);
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1"); //local host
    if (connect(c, (struct sockaddr *)&server, sizeof(server)) < 0) {
        // Here is my error
        printf("Error when connecting! %s\n",strerror(errno)); 
        return 1;
    }

    while(1) {
        char msg[100];
        printf("Give message: ");
        fgets(msg, sizeof(msg), stdin); 
        send(c, &msg, sizeof(msg), 0);
        char resp[100];
        recv(c, &resp, sizeof(resp), 0);
        printf("Received: %s\n", resp);
    }
close(c);
}
```

**EDIT**

Of course ! the error was actually in the server. I simply found it weired that the client sent the message, so I narrowed my view, didn't even bother looking back at the server.

**Since the error seems to be also in my server, I might end up asking another question and linking it here**

Server was listening to (12345) ...

Comment: Did you write a program that listens on port 1234? Try executing nc -l 127.0.0.1 1234 before to have a listener.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

According to the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/2/connect):

> **ECONNREFUSED**
>   No-one listening on the remote address.

---

In order to provide a simple remote endpoint that accepts your connection and sends back the received data (echo server), you could try something like this [python server](http://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#example) (or to use [netcat](http://linux.die.net/man/1/nc)):

```
import socket
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind(("localhost", 1234))
s.listen(1)
conn, addr = s.accept()
print 'Connected by', addr
while 1:
    data = conn.recv(1024)
    if not data: break
    conn.sendall(data)
conn.close()
```

Answer (score 5):

Your Answer is: You program is client and it need a server to connect. `nc` command create server and your program can connect to it.

```
[root@mg0008 work]# nc -l 127.0.0.1 1234 &
[1] 25380
[root@mg0008 work]# ./socket
Give message: Hello
Hello
```

Answer (score 2):

probably no server listening port 1234 in your local host

Comment: And how can I resolve that ? I barley understand some of this stuff

Comment: you will need write a program, i.e. "the server" listening to the port 1234, and run it in your local box, before you run your client.